# How to expand/collapse row details?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

How can I implement row details and expanding/collapsing of custom details component using react-data-grid?

I have table of users and I want to be able to see user details after click/double click on the user row. Something like this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate . It is possible using this component?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Look into [`accordion toggling`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) if so.

Comment: Well, not, I am not using bootstrap. But I can do sth like that accordion by myself, but how it will help me? How can I plug in it into the grid? As row custom renderer? Using `rowRenderer` and some events to expand/collapse details component? Like that: https://jsfiddle.net/f6mbnb8z/281/ ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example for React](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/hierarchy/) similar to the jquery version of the Kendo grid. The idea is that you can now use React Components for the Details. For example you may place a another grid into the template Grid to get hierarchy.

```
class DetailComponent extends GridDetailRow {
render() {
    return (
        <Grid data={this.props.dataItem.details}>
        </Grid>
    );
}
}
// ...
// ...
 <Grid
       detail={DetailComponent}
       expandField="expanded"
       expandChange={this.expandChange}
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the maintainers of react-data-grid.

We consider the Kendo example to represent 2 different features:-

- the ability to nest data in an expandable tree view
- the ability to render any component (e.g. a sub-grid) as that child view

At the moment, we only have support for the former (see http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/tree-view)

Nested Grids is something that is requested often, but unfortunately for now we do not currently support it. However, this may change in future.

HTH
@jpdriver

Comment: has support for rendering a sub grid been added yet?

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do, but the simplest maybe you can set the state of the component with the key of the cell clicked, and creating the component in a function, pass the value if should be collapsed or not, and return the collapsed or not component of that cell and render it.